# Why is Angular Router going to one of my child module pages and not my real home page?

Tags: angular, angular-router

In my Angular app, my main router config looks like this:

```
export const routes: Route[] = [
  { path: 'sign-in', component: SignInComponent},
  { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: 'app/user/user.module#UserModule'},
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', component: PageNotFoundComponent},
]
```

My `UserModule` has a router itself, with the configuration thus far of:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: UserHomeComponent},
];
```

The strange thing is that when I load the page, I get

> **User-Home Component Works!**

instead of the "Home Component Works" I am expecting.

I could not figure out why this was happening for a little while...

Answer (score 1):

I soon discovered the problem.

The problem was that I was **importing** `UserModule` in the imports of my root module. Since I am already lazily loading `UserModule` in the router, I do not need to `import` it in the root module - in fact, importing it makes my app load the `UserModule` routing module which replaces my app's home route with the `UserModule` home route. No good.

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    UserModule,
    SharedModule,
  ],
```

changed it to:

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    SharedModule,
  ],
```